Show that the $T$ is a compact operator
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ be bounded. Consider the partial differential equation $(P)$
\begin{align}
-\Delta u+u^5&=h \ \ \text{on }\Omega,
\newline u&-0\ \ \text{on }\partial\Omega.
\end{align}
Define the map
\begin{align}
T:\ L^6(\Omega)&\longrightarrow L^6(\Omega)
\newline w&\longmapsto Tw
\end{align}
where $Tw$ is the weak solution of the partial differential equation $(P_w)$
\begin{align}
-\Delta u+w^5&=h \ \ \text{on }\Omega,
\newline u&-0\ \ \text{on }\partial\Omega.
\end{align}
Since $Tw$ is the weak solution of $(P_w)$, it satisfies
\begin{align}
\int\limits_\Omega\big[\nabla (Tw)\nabla \varphi+w^5\varphi\big]d\mu=\int\limits_\Omega h\varphi d\mu,\ \forall\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega).\tag1
\end{align}
I want to show that $T$ is a compact operator, i.e $T$ is continuous and for any bounded set $B\subset L^6(\Omega)$, $\overline{T(B)}$ is compact.
My attempt
For the continuity of $T$, give $\{w_n\}\subset L^6(\Omega)$ such that $w_n\to w\in L^6(\Omega)$. We will show that $T(w_n)\to T(w) $ in $L^6(\Omega)$.
We have for any $\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega)$,
\begin{align}
\int\limits_\Omega\big[\nabla (Tw_n)\nabla \varphi+w_n^5\varphi\big]d\mu&=\int\limits_\Omega h\varphi d\mu.\tag2
\end{align}
Subtracting (1) for (2) and choose $\varphi=Tw_n-Tw$, we have
\begin{align}
\int\limits_\Omega\big|\nabla(Tw_n-Tw) \big|^2+\int\limits_\Omega(w^5_n-w^5)(Tw_n-Tw)=0.
\end{align}
Since $w^5_n\to w^5$, we have
\begin{align}
\int\limits_\Omega\big|\nabla(Tw_n-Tw) \big|^2\to0.
\end{align}
I got stuck right here. May anyone give me some guidance for the rest of the problem ?  I would appreciate any help.

You need to say why $w_n^5 \to w^5$ converges (in which space?) and why this implies the convergence of the gradients. (Sobolev embedding and dominated convergence can help here.)
The last equation implies that $Tw_n \to Tw$ in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ by Poincare inequality. Hence, $T: L^6(\Omega) \to H^1_0(\Omega)$ is continuous.
Use (1) to show that $T$ maps bounded sets to bounded sets (set $\phi: = Tw$).
Now use the compact embedding of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ into $L^6(\Omega)$ to conclude that $T$ is compact.

The missing step in the proof is
$$
\left| \int_\Omega (w_n^5-w^5)(Tw_n-Tw) dx \right| \le \|Tw_n-Tw\|_{L^6} \| w_n^5-w^5\|_{L^{6/5}} \\
\le C \|Tw_n-Tw\|_{H^1} \| w_n^5-w^5\|_{L^{6/5}},
$$
where I used Hoelder inequality and Sobolev embedding. Now prove that $\| w_n^5-w^5\|_{L^{6/5} } \to0$ by dominated convergence.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I wonder why we had to use the Sobolev embedding, why didn't we just use $|w_n^5-w^5|{L^{6/5} }\to0$ and $|Tw_n-Tw|{L^6}<\infty$ to conclude that the left side is convergent to $0$ ?

This is necessary to conclude that $|Tw_n - Tw|_{L^6} $ is bounded.
